# How to find/delete duplicate items in stack

Tags: python, stack, user-defined-functions

The items inside the stack should be unique. Is there a way I can delete the duplicate item inside the stack? And inform the user that his input is already inside the stack?

Here is my code:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, key):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.val = key

def printPreorder(root):
if root:
    print(root.val),
    printPreorder(root.left)
    printPreorder(root.right)

class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        return self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

print ("Create 3 words using the letters:")
root = Node('n')
root.right = Node('o')
root.left = Node ('w')
printPreorder(root)
print("-----------------------------------")


s1 = stack()
while (s1.size() <3):
    FirstList = (input("Enter the word you created: ")).lower()
    if FirstList == 'won' or FirstList == 'own' or FirstList == 'now':
        s1.push(FirstList)
        print(s1.items)
    
    else: 
        print('Try another word!')
```

Comment: One way to do this is to store a copy of the stack's contents in a list and search there, but it's not good if your stack has a lot of elements

Answer (score 0):

Ideally no you cannot traverse through a stack to find duplicate elements.
But since you are using a list for your stack implementation, you can traverse through it and find duplicate elements but this is not a good idea.

Instead, you can use another data structure, for example, a `set` can be used to keep track of all the unique elements you have seen so far. Every time `.push()` is called, you can check if the element is already present in the set. If it is not present, then you can add it to both the stack and set. If present, you can inform the user that it is already present in stack.

And remember to remove the element from the set when you pop from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to store unique values. A simple way to check if the stack has unique elements is to compare the size of the set of stack elements and the list of stack elements (since your implementation of a stack is a list).

```
def isDuplicate(self):
   return len(set(self.items())) != len(self.items())
```

To check if there's a duplicate element in the stack (implemented as a list), you can write an implementation that inserts your elements into a set, and at every step checks whether the element already exists inside the list.

```
def removeDuplicate(self):
   temp_set = set()
   for item in self.items():
      if item in temp_set:
         return item
   return None
```

And then you can remove that duplicate element from the stack using `self.items().pop(self.removeDuplicate())`